# Ordering output while printing association details in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, associations

I have a piece of code which is working nearly perfectly, but not quite. It's outputting a list of news stories and following the association I have created of customer->website->news.

However I wish to have them ordered by the field "DATE" which is in the news entity. Currently it is outputting in a seemingly random order, and any changes I make are not reflected when I print the data out (you can see in the code below I have endeavored to add a sort, but changing from ascending/descending order makes no difference).

```
<div class="News">
  <% @subject.customersAssociation.each do |customer| %>
    <% customer.websitesAssociation.each do |website| %>
  <% website.newsAssociation.sorted_by(field('DATE')).each do |news| %>
            <ul>
              <li>..Print data from |customer|... </li>
              <li>..Print data from |website|... </li>
              <li>..Print data from |news|... </li>
          </ul>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `order`, like this :

`website.newsAssociation.order(date: :desc)`

You can change to ascending order by specifying `:asc` instead of `:desc`